# show that solutions of a ODE are linearly independent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have
$$ty''+y'=0$$

and calculated it and got

$$y=c_1 \ln(t) + c_2$$

so that

$$y_1(t)= \ln(t)$$
$$y_2(t) = 1.$$

Now I need to show the linear independence of the solutions

so they are linearly dependent if the constants fulfill
$$\sum c_i x_i(t)  = 0 $$   for $c_i \neq 0.$

It is intuitively clear that aren't any $c_1, c_2 : c_1 \ln(t) = -c_2 $ $\forall t.$

But how can I prove it in a nice way?

Comment: consider the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I thought about it, so the Wronskian would give me det W(t) = 1/t, and that would suffice as a proof? since $1/t \neq 0$ $\forall t \in I$

Comment: I believe so:  $\frac1t\ne0\;\forall t\in \mathbb R$; by the way, you're assuming $t\ne0$?

Comment: well I think it has to be $t \neq 0$, due to ln(t) not being defined at zero? Can I do this assumption?

Comment: if $t=0$, the equation is $y'=0$, i.e., $y=C$

Comment: oh of course, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $t\ne0$; otherwise, the equation $ty''+y'=0$ is $y'=0$, i.e., $y=C$.

You are correct that, for $t\ne0$, the solution of $ty''+y'=0$

is $c_1y_1(t)+c_2y_2(t)$ with $y_1(t)=\ln t$ and $y_2(t)=1$.

These are linearly independent because the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)
$\begin{vmatrix}\ln t&1\\1/t&0\end{vmatrix}=-1/t\ne0$ for $t\in\mathbb R$.